# Ant is using wrong file class

Tags: java, ant

i'm trying to compile my project but ANT is telling me that is not finding a class when that class no exist in my project (it existed but i refactored the class and the name).

If i comment the line, ANT works fine..

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning up your build? But beyond that, it is really hard to help here, as we have no idea about the exact nature of your problem (see [mcve] please).

Comment: Error messages in detail and code snippets will go a long way to helping folks help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the issue..

My main problem was that in the log, there was an error in a line that wasn't in the java code..

It was like if ANT was compiling a previous version of my code.

So, I downloaded the code from my repository but with my changes and budum, ANT worked  fine!